# Pandas matching datetime.datetime value against pandas date type

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, subset

I'm trying to get day ago prices from one table that match the ids and date from a second table (for a performance reporting tool).

I'm using a pretty simple subset
where `dateLoop[0]` is `datetime.datetime(2013,1,10,0,0)`

```
olddate = np.datetime64(dateLoop[0])

pv = dfp[dfp['instrument'].isin(dayfp.instrument.unique()) \
 & dfp.date == olddate ]
```

and it raises the exception

`TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [bool]`

How can I get it to match a date range that hasn't been created in pandas and where its been imported as a dictionary so the datetime hasn't been indexed?

```
dfp = pd.DataFrame([
      dict(instrument = 'GE', price = 10, date = datetime.datetime(2013,1,10,0,0)),
      dict(instrument = 'INTC', price = 15, date = datetime.datetime(2013,1,10,0,0))
...]
```

and

```
dayfp =
`date   id instrument portfolio  position  price            sector  \
22 2013-01-11  153         PM  usequity     62000  82.82  Consumer Staples   
23 2013-01-11  154        CMS  usequity    217000  23.14         Utilities   
24 2013-01-11  155        EXC  usequity    181000  27.16         Utilities   
25 2013-01-11  156        AES  usequity    467000  10.81         Utilities   
26 2013-01-11  157        DOV  usequity     92000  53.95       Industrials   

         mv        wt  px0  
22  5134840  0.063798  NaN  
23  5021380  0.062389  NaN  
24  4915960  0.061079  NaN  
25  5048270  0.062723  NaN  
26  4963400  0.061668  NaN
```

I'm trying to populate px0 by searching on instrument and date from a large list of historical prices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python interprets

```
[dfp['instrument'].isin(['GE', 'INTC']) & dfp.date == olddate]
```

as

```
[(dfp['instrument'].isin(['GE', 'INTC']) & dfp.date)
 == olddate]
```

instead of

```
(dfp['instrument'].isin(['GE', 'INTC'])) & (dfp.date == olddate)
```

According to [operator precedence rules](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) `&` has higher precedence than `==`, so the two terms next to the `&` get bound together before the `==` is applied.

If you don't want to think deeply about operator precedence issues, always wrap your boolean expressions in parentheses to enforce the order of operations you desire.

---

```
import datetime as DT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dfp = pd.DataFrame([
      dict(instrument = 'GE', price = 10, date = DT.datetime(2013,1,10,0,0)),
      dict(instrument = 'INTC', price = 15, date = DT.datetime(2013,1,10,0,0))])

olddate = np.datetime64(DT.datetime(2013,1,10,0,0))

pv = dfp[(dfp['instrument'].isin(['GE', 'INTC'])) & (dfp.date == olddate)]
print(pv)
```

yields

```
        date instrument  price
0 2013-01-10         GE     10
1 2013-01-10       INTC     15
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just need to turn either of the two columns into the datatype of the other so that you can compare them. If so using these type conversions on one of the columns to get it into a matching type would solve your issue I'd imagine.

```
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 10, 0, 0)
>>> str(dt)
'2013-01-10 00:00:00'
>>> np.datetime64(str(dt))
numpy.datetime64('2013-01-10T00:00:00-0600')
>>> pd.to_datetime(str(dt))
Timestamp('2013-01-10 00:00:00', tz=None)
>>> np.datetime64(str(dt)).tolist()
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 10, 6, 0)
```

Does this give you the conversion you need? I cannot determine what exactly you are attempting to do, but these conversions should work for datetime.datetime to numpy.datetime64 and pd.Timestamp.

If you could add more exact example data and sample output, I may be able to tailor this to be more helpful....

Comment: Thanks @crazy. Tried those but they didn't work. I still can't subset on the date using any of these as the variable to match to.

Comment: There is also an issue with your operator precedence, I believe. You need to put a parenthesis around (dfp.date == olddate).